# can't see objects in MainPage.xaml.cs -xamarin-C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

can't see label or button from my MainPage.xaml
the error "The name greetinglabel does not exists in current content"

MainPage.xaml code

```
         <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:hello"
                      x:Class="hello.MainPage">

<StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="greetinglabel"
           Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <Entry x:Name="nameEntry"
           Placeholder="write your name"/>
    <Button Text="say hello"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs code

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Xamarin.Forms;

 namespace hello
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Suggest that you can refer to this demo.Add you can modify code in demo to find resaon.https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/PhonewordMultiscreen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your stack layout in Content page content like this.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="greetinglabel"
           Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <Entry x:Name="nameEntry"
           Placeholder="write your name"/>
    <Button Text="say hello"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: For this i have to see your full code. If the above solution helps you then please mark the answer as the accepted one. :)

Comment: same as the code in the question now when I write greetinglabel I can see it in the MainPage.xaml.cs but new error say hello.ios - not available like this https://b.top4top.net/p_1057kizj41.png